# Load Excel 2007 file with columns more than 255 columns into SQL Server table using SQL Server 2012 Import Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an Excel .xlsx file that has data columns extending to 316 columns.
Each column has data specific to that column. I want to load these data into a SQL Server table.

I tried to use the SQL Import Export wizard for loading this Excel file into the SQL Server table. However the Excel is not loaded fully.The data is only loaded up to 255 columns. The columns after 255th are not getting loaded into the table.

Is there any way to load the excel with more than 300 columns into a SQL Server table

Comment: I think using [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services) is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Today we have many tool for make that, but if you haven't licence for SSIS or you can't buy some software ..you can try this.

- Split your excel, but I prefere convert xls to csv ( is better ) ,
  put a ID (equals) each csv file and load with Import Export Wizard
  in diferente tables.After just with a JOIN is enough.
- You can use some language , for example python with (Python SQL
  driver - pyodbc /Python SQL driver - pymssql ) and make a script for
  load csv , in Internet there are many examples.